# statweave problem

Tags: packages, pdftex, installing, statweave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Problem in StatWeave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/problem-in-statweave)

I installed `statweave` on Windows 7. The installation is like this:

- MiKTeX 2.9 is installed in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\`
- `statweave` installed in `C:\`
- Other configurations: only changed the arguments of the Stata 11 which is in `C:\stat11\stata.exe`.

At the moment, I put `statweave.sty` in the code folder together with `.rnw` files.

### Compiling:

When I compile the `.rnw` files it produces the `.tex` and `.eps` file. For the graph it works and I am able to convert it to `.pdf` (from `.eps`) but for the `.tex` it doesn't work; pdflatex stops working.

Where should `statweave.sty` be placed? Anyone with a working configuration?

Comment: Have you read this: [Problem in StatWeave](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16398/5764)?

Comment: `Statweave.sty` should be placed in your local texmf folder. See [How do I manually install a package in MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. We had the same problem with SASweave as well. What we found the fix to be there would be to place the .sty files in the same location that the .tex files were being run from. STATweave however, is a beast of a different nature.